# What's the word/verb meaning "to bend something inwards"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm struggling hard to remember a word I came across many months ago. It's not an uncommon word as far as I can remember. The word in question means, again if I can recall correctly, *to bend something inwards.*  I think it's a synonym of, or at least related to, *telescope* (as in *The cars *telescoped* during the collision*). I also have a vague remembrance that the word starts with the letter 's'. I've been cudgeling my brains hard over this, but the word is still eluding me.

I know this is probably not the right place to be asking such a frivolous question, but I'm pretty sure I'll be rid in no time of this compulsive obsession to recall the word ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's funny that the word should come back to me after posting about it here when it'd been eluding me for a long time now.

The word I'd been after was **stave**:

> to smash a hole in

*stove in the boat*

> also : to crush or break inward

*staved in several ribs*

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: I’m glad you thought of the word you were trying to think of, but this is not a good answer to the question, as “smash a hole in/crush or break inward” is very different from “bend something inward”.

Comment: Moby Dick is fully of "stove boat[s]". But beware, it is usually about something that has staves, like a barrel or boat. Not just anything.

Answer (score 9):

Whether this is the lost word in your head I cannot say, but in some circumstances you might use **scrunch**.

> [Merriam Webster (M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrunch)
>
> Scrunch:
>
> to draw or squeeze together tightly; crumple — often used with *up*; to cause (something) to draw together —usually used with *up*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scrunch)
>
> to make something or yourself smaller to fit into a small space

Collins discusses a little more than M-W and Cambridge. Here is an extract:

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scrunch)
>
> If you scrunch something, you squeeze it or bend it so that it is no longer in its natural shape and is often crushed.
>
> Her father scrunched his nose. [VERB noun]
>
> Her mother was sitting bolt upright, scrunching her white cotton gloves into a ball. [VERB noun + into]

Answer (score 7):

**to concertina**:

OED

> **1.** *transitive*. **To cause (a thing) to fold, collapse, or wrinkle in a manner suggestive of a concertina's bellows. Also figurative.**
>
> 2001   P. H. Jackson Chameleon Candidate i. 1   *The force of the crash had concertinaed the vehicle.*
>
> **2.** *intransitive.* **To fold, collapse, or wrinkle in the manner of a concertina's bellows. Frequently with prepositional phrase.**
>
> 1998   C. Barker Galilee vi. 346   *It [sc. a Mercedes] had concertinaed against the rear of the truck and was virtually unrecognizable.*

Answer (score 6):

**Crumple** is used in cars, such as a [crumple zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crumple_zone).

> to press, bend, or crush out of shape
>
> to cause to collapse

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crumple)

Comment: That's right, @jimm101. Not the word I was looking for, though. I have mentioned it above (in comments) that it was actually _stave in_ that I was looking for. But thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This word does not start with S but it certainly carries the meaning you are looking for. It is a verb that can be used both transitively and intransitively:

***Incurvate** (or incurve)*

> to curve or cause to curve inwards ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/incurvate))

e.g.

> - Gravity *incurvates* the rays.
> - The body *incurvates* a little at the back. ([finedictionary.com](http://www.finedictionary.com/incurvate.html))

It's a start. Maybe looking up its synonyms might help you find your s word.

Answer (score -3):

Here are a couple of words that meet your criteria:

**Shrink**

> Become or make smaller in size or amount.

**Squeeze**

> Firmly press (something soft or yielding), typically with one's fingers.

**Shorten**

> Make or become shorter.

**Squash**

> Crush or squeeze (something) with force so that it becomes flat, soft, or out of shape.

**Squelch**

> To fall or stamp on so as to crush

**Summarize**

> To make a summary of; state or express in a concise form.

**Synopsize**

> To make a synopsis of.

**Specificate**

> To give specificity to.

**Syncopate**

> To shorten or produce by syncope

Comment: None of those words.

Comment: Maybe Syncopate? (Also I don't have 50 rep so I couldn't post my response as a comment to your post)

Comment: @Grift If you can't comment, you need to [write a good answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10091). We don't like answers in comments much anyway. See also [multi-word answers](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/)

Comment: What? This person already had a good understanding of the word they were looking for, so how can an answer that gives only one word and a definition be considered better then an answer that gives multiple possible words that the person could be asking for? If this question was asking: "What word can I use to describe X thing" then I could understand but it's not.

Comment: Anyway I "improved" my post but the correction doesn't help the author of this post at all (since again they were looking for a **specific** word) so it's frankly a ridiculous criticism.